# How to save the command history in a text file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to save the value of a variable from MATLAB command history in a text. I am trying the command:

```
Save([d:/work/abc.txt], 'z1', '-ASCII');
```

An error appears

```
Error: input charecter is not valid in MATLAB environment or expression.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing are the quotes within the brackets for denoting string.

```
['string']
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `save` (with lower case for "s").

Also the filename should be defined as a string: enclose it withi two '; also you do not need the `[]` unless, for example, you want to build a string using a variable and / or any function to create part of the filename (e. g.

```
['d:/work/abc_' num2str(k) '.txt']
```

assuming `k` value is `3`) to get `d:/work/abc_3.txt`

Try change your code to:

```
save(['d:/work/abc.txt'], 'z1', '-ASCII');
```

Hope this helps.

Qapla

Comment: What do you mean with "_This is not working_"? I've tested the two lines of code and they both work: the first one generate the string `d:/work/abc_3.txt` (as written in the answer); the purpose of this instruction was to explain when you need to enclose a string within `[ ]`. The second instruction acutally creates the `ASCII` file _abc.txt_ in the _d:/work_ folder. As written in the answer your original code was not working because you did not enclosed the filename within two `'`.